# Jquery change and submit

Tags: jquery, submit, onchange

Am I wrong or something? Trying to make it work with $.post() but nothing happens. even with a simple alert I get nothing. Any ideas?

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".browse").change(function(){
                          $('#form').submit(function(e){
              alert( "Yipee" );
                          preventDefault();
              });
    });
});
```

Note that

```
    $(".browse").change(function(){$('#form').submit();});
```

Is working fine

Comment: preventDefault is not bound to the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place the submit event handler outside

```
 $(".browse").change(function () {

        });
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            alert("Yipee");
            preventDefault();
        });
```

if you want to trigger the submit you shoul call like this

```
$(".browse").change(function () {
$('#form').trigger("submit");
        });
```

Comment: Anoop I am not using submit buttons